# Why noexcept move constructor is not getting called during vector reallocation?

Tags: c++, c++14, noexcept

As we know when new element  is added to std::vector (via push_back)  it’s possible that it lacks space for it and for these cases vector allocates larger chunk of memory to hold all its elements and then transfer from existing chunk to new one.In C++98 this is done via copying elements from old location and then destroying those objects and because of this it can offer strong exception guarantee and in c++11 it can be optimized with move constructor provided it is noexcept but what will happen if my destructor is noexcept(false) then why optimization is not happening ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class X
{
public:
    X()
    {
    }
    X(const X& ob) noexcept
    {
      std::cout<<"Copy Constructor...."<<std::endl;
    }
    X(X&& ob) noexcept
    {
       std::cout<<"Move Constructor...."<<std::endl;
    }
    ~X() noexcept(false)
    {
    }
};
int main()
{
   std::vector<X> myobs;
   for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
   {
      myobs.push_back(X());
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Why Copy Constructor is called in above scenario and also note that if i make destructor as noexcept (Default Behavior) then only move constructor will be called.

To add my understanding of strong exception guarantee (in vector::push_back) is none of the elements in old memory is destroyed until all are successfully copied and this means destructors are called at the end so it doesn't matter whether they are noexcept or not

Comment: http://ideone.com/UFfri3

Comment: Yeah, the throwing destructor is at fault: https://ideone.com/lcP4FW See notes here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible

Comment: That is the question why throwing destructor is creating problem when all objects should be first copied or moved and then destruction will happen, so if move is noexcept then destructor is throwing or not throwing should not matter

Comment: @KerrekSB this desctructor doesn't throw

Comment: @M.M: No, but it's not noexcept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the specification of `is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>`, which is currently specified to check whether the expression

```
T(declval<T&&>())
```

is noexcept, but that involves the destructor (of the temporary) as well as the move constructor. This is arguably a library defect, subject of the ongoing [LWG 2116](http://wg21.link/lwg2116). GCC is correct to follow the specification; it is the specification itself that is bad.

Comment: I'm not sure why some of the committee members were reluctant to fix the issue ; it's already UB if a vector element destructor actually throws an exception (res.on.functions/2.4), so the destructor's exception specification can be ignored

Comment: `T(declval<T&&>())` is from C++17 drafts; in C++14 the specification was that if we have a function `T&& create() noexcept;` , then `T t( create() );` should be valid and non-throwing, and I don't see where that would involve a destructor call

Comment: @M.M: Same thing, right, the destruction of the temporary?

Comment: are you referring to `t`, or the return value of `create`?  (which is a reference , not a temporary)

Comment: @M.M: No, you're right, I'm not sure. In C++11 it was different yet again.

Comment: @M.M: I think the problem is that you can't really check for the noexceptness of a statement, so the actual implementations end up using `noexcept` on some *expression* which invariably includes the destruction of a temporary. That's why the LWG issue suggests an alternative specification in terms of placement new, which would produce an expression that only touches the aspect of the type that's of interest.